# How to unit-test post request for multiple checkboxes with the same name under webapp2

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, webapp2

Using webapp2 I create unit tests for a form where there are checkboxes for votes so multiple values can be posted for the `vote` field and they are retrieved via `request.POST.getall('vote')`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vote" value="Better">
<input type="checkbox" name="vote" value="Faster">
<input type="checkbox" name="vote" value="Stronger">
```

In the unit test I tried passing a list:

```
response = app.get_response('/vote',
  POST={'vote': [u'Better', u'Faster', u'Stronger']},
  headers=[('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8')]
)
```

But looks like it's simply converted to a string:

```
votes = self.request.POST.getall('vote')
# => [u"[u'Better', u'Faster', u'Stronger']"]
```

How can I pass multiple values for `vote` that will be retrieved as a list via `request.POST.getall()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POST data is encoded using query string encoding, and multiple items by the same name are represented by repeating the key with different values. For instance:

```
vote=Better&vote=Faster&vote=Stronger
```

Python has library functions to do this for you, though:

```
urllib.urlencode({
  'vote': ['Better', 'Faster', 'Stronger'],
}, True)
```

The second argument (`True`) to `urlencode` is called 'doseq', and instructs urlencode to encode sequences as lists of separate elements.

Answer (score 1):

The webtest library is helpful for these test cases.

http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/latest/index.html#form-submissions