# Django unit testing; POST checkboxes with multiple values

Tags: django, unit-testing, post, checkbox

I am trying to run a unit test on a form with multiple checkboxes, but cannot figure out how to send the POST data. The most similar question I can find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313124/how-to-unit-test-post-request-for-multiple-checkboxes-with-the-same-name-under-w). But how do I embed that url-encoded piece into the POST with the other form data?

If I do something like this, my test errors out and says     classes = request.POST.getlist('class_choices')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'getlist':

```
    request = HttpRequest()
    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['fname'] = 'A'
    request.POST['lname'] = 'Student'
    request.POST['email'] = 'me@name.com'
    request.POST['class_choices'] = urllib.urlencode({
            'class_choices': ['1', '2'],
    }, True)
    request.POST['passwd'] = 'password'
    request.POST['conpasswd'] = 'password'
    response = success(request)
    self.assertIn('My Browser', response.content.decode())
```

But if I do this, I get an error on     fname = request.POST['fname']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

```
    request.POST = urllib.urlencode({
            'class_choices': ['1', '2'],
            'fname': 'A',
            'lname': 'Student',
            'email': 'me@name.com',
            'passwd': 'password',
            'conpasswd': 'password'
    }, True)
    response = success(request)
```

Comment: why don't you use normal Django test client? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#testing-tools

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was following this [http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch05.html#_processing_a_post_request_on_the_server] (tutorial for Selenium / Django), which shows it using a different method. Your way seems to work (I get a different error, which is progress), so I would be happy to accept...thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after trying out a couple other things, I'm basically going to say there is "technically" no answer to my question...I could not find any way to create a checkbox-type POST argument using HttpRequest. However, doing it the 'right' way with the Django test client as Hieu Nguyen suggested does allow for that capability. You just have to encapsulate the multiple options in parantheses, as:

```
    response = c.post('/success/',{
        'fname': 'A',
        'lname': 'Student',
        'email': 'me@name.com',
        'passwd': 'password',
        'conpasswd': 'password',
        'class_choices': ('1','2'),
    })
```

Comment: Previously with Pyramid I've used WebOb's MultiDict https://webob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/webob.html#webob.multidict.MultiDict ... But this is much simpler - and seems to be a good test. Thanks!